# Claiming liquid peg-in: „The txoutproof must contain bitcoinTx and only bitcoinTX“

Tags: sidechains, liquid

I‘m trying to do a liquid pegin. Generated the pegin address and sent funds to it, waited < 102 blocks. When trying to claim them with

```
liquid-cli claimpegin “rawtransaction“ “txoutproof“
```

The result is

```
    Error code: -8 
Error message: The txoutproof must contain bitcoinTx and only bitcoinTX
```

The txoutproof looks longer than in the example of bitcoin-cli help page and was done on a -txindex enabled full node `gettxoutproof “[\“txid\“]“`

```
00008020f2e6bcdb...
```

I‘m thankful for any clues what could be wrong. Am I doing something wrong with the claimpegin input parameter format?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: This is really a service question.

Comment: The proof length is variable in size based on the number of transactions in the block it is a proof for, so that isn’t unusual.

Comment: The raw transaction and txoutproof didn‘t match due to a copy/paste error.